# Android - sendTextMessage Message not showingup in SMS Apps

Tags: android, sms

I am writing an app which will send an SMS automatically to a given number on some conditions, SMS code is working and SMS is also delivered.. but the sent SMS are not showing up in any of the ***other*** SMS Clients/Apps installed...

```
String phoneNumber = "1234512345";
String message = "Test Message";
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

What am i missing?
I want the sent SMS (*sent by my app*) to show up in other SMS apps which are installed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you have sent SMS progrmatically but you **haven't informed SMS Content Provider** so it will not get your message unless you inform it.

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
 values.put("address", "1234512345"); 
 values.put("body", "Test Message"); 
 getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

Make sure to include below permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score -2):

use broadcast receiver in receiving side application

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     String str="";
     String from="";


        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                    
               str += messages[i].getMessageBody().toString();
               from = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress().toString();
            }

           if(from.equals("123456789")){ 

           str= str.trim();

           abortBroadcast();
           Intent intt = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                   intt.putExtras("message",str); 
           intt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(intt);
           }
       }
```

in your mainActivity write some code to display the obtained message. the message will be in the intent. so get the String from it.

here the broadcast receiver, receives messages from only number "123456789". the messages from this number will not go to inbox of ur mobile. if u want to see in inbox also remove the method abortBroadcast().

Comment: it will get the messages from the specified number mentioned there i.e "123456789"

Comment: why are we making things complex here? Solution provided by @PareshMayani is to the point and works...